# Tkinter exiting mainloop when navigating between pages

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have tried various functionality in tkinter to navigate between pages in my GUI. I am trying to achieve a GUI with a next and previous button, which closes one page, and opens another.

```
def nextPage():
    ws.withdraw()
    import page2
```

Where it perfectly takes me to the next page when I add this as a command to a button.

When I try to use this same logic when returning to the page, it does it fine as well.

The problem arises when I try to import page2 for a second time. It ends up exiting the mainloop and closing out of the program.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Importing a module for the second time *does absolutely nothing* - the module already exists in memory.  Instead of having top-level code in your imported modules, you want to define a function that you can call whenever you want the module's action to take place.

Comment: We can't reproduce this problem with such a tiny block of code. Please try to create a [mcve] for this question.

Answer (score 0):

`import module` effectively brings into your code the module's code. So recommend `import` at the beginning of your code. Then in your function you refer to the module `page2`.

```
import page2 
def nextPage():
    ws.withdraw()
    page2.run()
```

Your `page2` would need to be changed so that its code is inside the function `def run():` so that on the first import at the beginning it will not run.

You can test this if you put import at the beginning of your code without changing the module code - you will see `page2` run at that point before the rest of your code.